# How to show one hour before and after one hour from the reminder time

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I need want to show a reminder before one hour and after one-hour  from the reminder time now it's showing full that reminder date

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var dsr = <?=$todo['dsr']?>;
 let dsr_str ='<ul>';
 $.each(dsr, function(index, item){
 let now = new moment(item['reminder_date']);
  dsr_str += '<li>'+item['company']+' | '+item['phone']+' | <b>'+now.format("hh:mm A")+'</b></li>';
    });
    dsr_str +='</ul>'
$(document).Toasts('create', {
      title: 'DSR Reminder',
      // position: 'bottomLeft',
      class: 'bg-danger', 
      body: dsr_str
    })
  }
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this to format the date object:

```
const d = new Date()
const h = d.getHours();
const r = h.toString().padStart(2,"0")+":"+d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2,"0") + h>12?"pm":"am"
```

Comment: actually I don't how to put in the code can you help me undø _